# Custom labels in Chaco Legend

Tags: python, legend, chaco

I'd like to change the line labels on a chaco Legend because my labels need to be ascending floats:

```
1,2,3,4
```

But it is string sorting, so I'm getting:

```
1, 10, 11, 2, 21  etc...
```

I noticed the documentation seems unfinished in regard to this:

http://chaco.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user_manual/basic_elements/overlays.html#legend

I've tried setting the legends labels manually:

```
self.plot.legend.labels = list([i for i in self.mylist])
```

I'm using a colormap, so this is very noticeable as the legend shows blue lines and red lines mixed seemingly randomly due to the string sorting.

### Below is a minimal working example

This example does not use the same colormap I'm using, but shows how the line ordering in the legend is not sorted.  It's not important which colormap is used, what's important is the string sorting in the legend gives unwanted aesthetics.

```
from traits.api import *
from chaco.api import *
from traitsui.api import *
from chaco.example_support import COLOR_PALETTE
from enable.api import ComponentEditor
import numpy as np


class TestPlot(HasTraits):

    plot = Instance(Plot)

    traits_view = View( Item('plot', editor=ComponentEditor(), show_label=False) )

    def _plot_default(self):
        data = ArrayPlotData()
        plot = Plot(data)

        x = np.linspace(0,10,100)
        data.set_data('x', x)

        for i, freq in enumerate(range(1,20,3)):
            y = 'line_%s' % freq
            color = tuple(COLOR_PALETTE[i])
            data.set_data(y, i*x)
            plot.plot(('x', y), name=y, color=color)

        plot.legend.visible = True


        return plot


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestPlot().configure_traits()
```

See screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Sorry for all of the traitsui/chaco questions lately.  I'm wrapping up an old simulation program and figured I'll post these as I come across them as they'll likely help others in the future.

Comment: What are your desired colors, and can you post minimal code that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: See updates.  Using default colormap for brevity, but in my program, I'm using a matplotlib colormap that goes from red to blue with a constant gradation.

Comment: Not yet an answer, but as a workaround, what about tweaking the labels to "line__1" etc? (i.e. insert an extra underscore for single-digit numbers). By some standards, that would be more readable.

Comment: Thanks.  That still messes up the sorting though.  My order becomes:

10, 13, 16, 19, 1, 4, 7

Comment: You can add leading zeros for one digit numbers by changing the line `y = 'line_%s' % freq` to `y = 'line_%02d' % freq`. I assume you have no more than 99 graphs otherwise you need to change the `02` to `03`. Then your legend should be correctly sorted. See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language for more information on the string format

Comment: Can you post this as an answer, so I can accept it?  Thanks!

Comment: Also, what if the lines are floats?  Like 1.1, 1.2, 1.3..., would this work?  I tried doing %02f, but then it doesn't round them.  IE I get 1.1000000 1.20000000

Comment: The format `0#` where `#` is a number, means that in the string the number uses `#` positions and if the number is smaller than the given width it is filled with trailing zeros. If you want floating point numbers with one digit as fractional part and a 2 digits as integral part use `%04.1f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add leading zeros for one digit numbers by changing the line

```
y = 'line_%s' % freq
```

to

```
y = 'line_%02d' % freq
```

I assume you have no more than 99 graphs otherwise you need to change the `02` to `03`. Then your legend should be correctly sorted.

See https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language for more information on the string format specifiers.

The format `0#` where `#` is a number, means that in the string the number uses `#` positions and if the number is smaller than the given width it is filled with trailing zeros. If you want floating point numbers with one digit as fractional part use `%04.1f`

Comment: Thanks for this.  Wanted to remark that the more general solution to how to set chaco line labels in the legend arbitrarily (ie pass in a desired list of strings) is still an outstanding issue.

Comment: @AdamHughes To add on your problem of setting the legend's labels arbitrarily: In your question you write that you tried the line `self.plot.legend.labels = list([i for i in self.mylist])`. Is `self.mylist` a list of the actual plot names that you use in your call to `plot.plot`? To keep with your short example: The entries of `mylist` should be of the form `'line_#'` where # is one of the numbers you use `(1, 4, 7, ..., 19)`. See this comment in chaco`s source: https://github.com/enthought/chaco/blob/032f21a732e968616fc2bbb3016b0fffd7d51db2/chaco/legend.py#L375

Comment: No, the labels are arbitrary string names.  Thank you for sharing that source code, I didn't realize it had to be the same name (although it's kind of obvious now!)

Yes, this does work now, that I can sort my values arbitrarily!  Looks like you've provided me with two solutions!

Maybe make a solution1 and solution2 in the accepted answer?

Looking back, I'm really not sure what I did wrong originally to think this approach didn't work...

Answer (score 2):

To sort your labels properly you need just to apply natural sorting. Install "natsort" library and insert two lines in your code:

```
from natsort import natsorted
...
plot.legend.labels = natsorted(plot.plots.keys())
```

This will do the trick.

Comment: Thanks I never knew about this library.